# How to create dynamic progress bar with flask?

Tags: python, flask, ria

I wonder if ther is flask extension or snippet that allows dynamic client web page data update (I need it  for progress bar alike this one:
[image]

yet if there is a general SignalR alike library to create dynamic web application it would solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to simulate Non-Blocking I/O Model similar to SignalR you can have a look at Flask-SocketIO - https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO.